# Slow response from SQL Azure database using odbc_fetch_array in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, azure

I have a database in Azure.  When I run a query that returns 300 records via SMSS, I get the results very quickly.  However, when I try to get the results using odbc_fetch_array in php, the response time is slow (15 - 20 seconds).  If I limit the result set to a few records (in php), the response is quick.  How can I reduce the delay?

Here is my code:

```
    //CONNECTIONS  *************************************************
try {
    $connect = odbc_connect(odbcname,'user','password');
    $result = odbc_exec($connect,$sql); 
    $applicants = array();
//slow response in while loop below
    while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($result) ) {
        array_push($applicants,$row);
    }
    $err = (odbc_error() ? odbc_errormsg($connect) : '');
    odbc_close($connect);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die();
}
```

The web server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter.
The odbc driver is "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server".

Comment: Is your database PaaS or IaaS? I am assuming IaaS based on the OS version. Perhaps take a look at the resources on the PHP machine while running the query or fire up SQL Profiler locally as something in your application code may be generating excessive load.

Comment: Have you tried using PDO instead of odbc_*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to setup the connection to use the ODBC_CURSOR

```
//CONNECTIONS  *************************************************
try {
    $connect = odbc_connect(odbcname,'user','password', SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC); //<--------
    $result = odbc_exec($connect,$sql); 
    $applicants = array();
//slow response in while loop below
    while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($result) ) {
        array_push($applicants,$row);
    }
    $err = (odbc_error() ? odbc_errormsg($connect) : '');
    odbc_close($connect);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die();
}
```

However the Microsoft recommended approach for accessing SQL Database from PHP is to use the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server available [here](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php)

Here a little (not tested example) by Microsoft examples to connect to Azure SQL Server.

```
$server = "tcp:<value of SERVER from section above>";
$user = "<value of USERNAME from section above>"@SERVER_ID;
$pwd = "password";
$db = "testdb";

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, array("UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>$db));

if($conn === false){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
}

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID > ?";

$cursorType = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);

$params = array(1)

$getProducts = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params, $cursorType);
if ( $getProducts === false)
   die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) );


if(sqlsrv_has_rows($getProducts))
{

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
           //ADD CODE HERE
    }

}

/* Free the statement and connection resources. */
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $getProducts );
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
```

On azure site you can find a step-by-step tutorial on how to connect to Sql Server with php, [see here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-php-how-to-use/#Setup)

Here you can find documentation about Microsoft Drivers for PHP for Sql Server [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638075(SQL.10).aspx)